# React Native "is not a function"

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

when i export a class as 'export default AvatarStore;' versus 'export default new AvatarStore();' i get the following error trying to use its methods in other classes...  Is using the new syntax correct?

[image: not a function]
here is the code:

```
import { List } from 'immutable';
    import EventEmitter from 'events';
    import Utils from '../utils/Utils.js'
    import RestService from '../services/RestService'
    import RestCallStatus from '../constants/RestCallStatus'
    import Avatar from '../models/Avatar'

    const CHANGE_EVENT = 'change';
    const TAG = 'AvatarStore';


    class AvatarStore extends EventEmitter {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this._populateRestCallStatus = RestCallStatus.NOT_REQUESTED;
        this._populated = false;
        this._dataStore = List();
    }

    populate(){
        RestService.getAllAvatars(this.handleSuccess.bind(this), this.handleFailure.bind(this));
        this._populateRestCallStatus = RestCallStatus.STARTED
    }

    handleSuccess(serviceName, jsonData){
        Utils.logMethod(TAG, 'handleSuccess ' + serviceName);
        if(jsonData.length > 0){  this._dataStore = List().clear(); }
        jsonData.forEach((entity) => {
            this._dataStore = this._dataStore.push(new Avatar(entity))
        });
        this._populated = true;
        this._populateRestCallStatus = RestCallStatus.SUCCESS;
        this.emitChange();
    }

    handleFailure(serviceName, error){
        Utils.logMethod(TAG, 'handleFailure');
        this._populateRestCallStatus = RestCallStatus.FAILED
        console.error(`Server call ${serviceName} failed with error: ${serviceName}!`)
    }

    getItems(){
        //Utils.logMethod(TAG, 'getItems');
        return this._dataStore;
    }

    getItemById(itemId){
        return Utils.findArrayElementById(this._dataStore, itemId);
    }

    getPopulated(){
        return this._populated;
    }

    addChangeListener(callback) {
        this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
    }

    removeChangeListener(callback) {
        this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
    }

    emitChange() {
        Utils.logMethod(TAG, 'emitChange');
        this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
    }
}
export default new AvatarStore();
```

Answer (score 1):

`export default AvatarStore` means that you want to export class. in `export default new AvatarStore()` case, you export instance of class (object). So you need to use the one it makes sense in your case - use the first if you want to have more instances of AvatarStore, otherwise you can use the second one.

Of course in the first case you need to make new instance somewhere after you import it.